# Moving rigged/animated object breaks it?

Tags: animation, rigging, geometry

I am trying to move a rigged and animated mesh to the origin, since when I export it to fbx and import it in unity, as soon as I hit play it shifts to the offset it has in blender.

[image]

Unfortunately, if I go to object mode and drag both the mesh and armature to the origin, this happens when I move on the timeline in Blender:
[image]

Any idea? It's driving me insane. I can't think of redoing all of the actions for such a small oversight.

Comment: Have you tried moving just the armature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like it might have been caused by auto-key. Although, after re-enabling it the issue did not come back. Very strange.

Comment: Hi, @NemoPS. You can mark your own answer as accepted, by clicking the tick, to clear it up.